# Hibernate @Formula Case statement

Tags: hibernate, case, formula

I'm trying to create the following formula in hibernate:

```
@Formula(value = "case when orderStatus=com.mypackage.model.OrderStatus.REJECTED then 0 else 1 ")
private int openStatus;
```

I get the following Exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '.OrderStatus.REJECTED then 0 else 1  as formula0_ from Orders order0_
>   order by c' at line 1

Is it possible to use the case in formula?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to add an "END" at the end of the SQL-Query.
Try the following:

```
@Formula(value = "case when orderStatus=com.mypackage.model.OrderStatus.REJECTED then 0 else 1 end")
private int openStatus;
```

Comment: I can confirm that ending `END` is necessary - at least for H2 databases.

Answer (score 2):

In the [`@Formula` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785) only common SQL code is allowed. When Hibernate queries the database, the formula will be inserted as a sub-select. No HQL or Java code is allowed in the formula's value.

From the Hibernate documentation:

> You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property into a column.

Assuming we have a getter annotated such that:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) from t_child c WHERE c.parent_id = parent_id)")
public int getChildCount() {
    return childCount;
}
```

Then Hibernate will generate this query:

```
SELECT this_.parent_id                        AS parent1_0_1_,
       this_.name_                            AS name2_0_1_,

       -- Block start
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   t_child c
        WHERE  c.parent_id = this_.parent_id) AS formula0_1_,
       -- Block end

       tchild1_.parent_id                     AS parent3_3_,
       tchild1_.child_id                      AS child1_3_,
       tchild1_.child_id                      AS child1_1_0_,
       tchild1_.parent_id                     AS parent3_1_0_,
       tchild1_.name_                         AS name2_1_0_
FROM   test.t_parent this_
       LEFT OUTER JOIN test.t_child tchild1_
                    ON this_.parent_id = tchild1_.parent_id
WHERE  this_.parent_id =?
```

I tried to highlight the block that is created due to the `@Formula` annotation. Hope this helps to understand, how Hibernate formulas work and which format is expected for the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it this way:

```
@Formula(value = "case when orderStatus='REJECTED' then 0 else 1 ")
private int openStatus;
```